# R setdiff function on vector of dates leads to strange results

Tags: r, date, vector

I'm trying to get a vector of all the working days between to dates with the following code:

```
days_of_month = seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2017-01-31"), by="days")
sundays = c(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2017-01-08"), as.Date("2017-01-15"), as.Date("2017-01-22"), as.Date("2017-01-29"))
```

When I do:

```
working_days = setdiff(days_of_month, sundays)
```

The return value of setdiff is a vector of strange values:

```
[1] 17168 17169 17170 17171 17172 17173 17175 17176 17177 17178 17179 17180
[13] 17182 17183 17184 17185 17186 17187 17189 17190 17191 17192 17193 17194
[25] 17196 17197
```

What are those values? And how I get a vectors of the days that are in `days_of_month` but not in `sundays`?

Comment: Perhaps `as.Date(setdiff(days_of_month, sundays), origin = "1970-01-01")`? You want to revise the vector, Sunday. That is not working.

Comment: These strange values are simply the numbers of days since 1970-01-01 (the default origin).

Comment: `days_of_month[!days_of_month %in% sundays]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are internal numeric value of R S3 class Date. You can see the numeric value by `as.numeric(days_of_month)`. Or, you can convert the result to `Date` by `as.Date(working_days, origin="1970-01-01")`.